# Web application not loading fully on iphone5s

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, web-applications

I have created a web application, That runs a preloader before displaying content on the page and the preloader is a full screen view with basic content like `loading` on it. 
Here is the code I'm using for the preloader

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
       $('.loader-main').addClass('loader-inactive');
    },0)   
});
```

My loader div looks like this

```
    <div id="page-preloader">
        <div class="loader-main">
            <div class="container">
              Loading content
            </div>
           *some image here*
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the style for the loader both active and inactive state

```
    .loader-main{
        position:fixed;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        right:0px;
        bottom:0px;
        z-index:999;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background:linear-gradient(45deg,#ffd5f5,#ffffff, #ffd5f5);
        will-change: opacity;
        transition:all 250ms ease; 
    }
    .loader-active{
        will-change: opacity;
        transition:all 350ms ease;
        opacity:1!important;
    }
    .loader-inactive{
        will-change: opacity;
        transition:all 250ms ease;
        opacity:0!important;
        pointer-events: none!important;
    }
```

This works perfectly on the following tested devices:

Windows, Mac, Android (chrome), iphone8, iphone6s.  But while testing on iphone5s, It keeps the loading view on and never fades out, however other contents of the page can be seen since the loader has an opacity of 80%,

I've made researches but can't find any thing, Removed the preloader and it worked fine on the iphone5s, However we can't have the App without a preloader.

Comment: What experiments have you tried? Like, changing the timeout milliseconds argument? Anything?

Comment: @Pointy Only trial was removing the loader from the page, and it worked fine!

Comment: There might be some other things to try also. It's not clear what this "preloader" is supposed to do, especially if it has a very short time to do it in.

Comment: The `$(document).ready()` in jquery only performs the function withing it if the document is ready, hence it only hides the preloader when the document is ready!

Comment: You posted an inadequate amount of code for anybody to help.

Comment: your problem might be because of `addClass`, which might not replace the `loader-active`. i.e u need to replace `loader-active` with `loader-inactive` instead of just adding both at the same time`.